# Make docked cells scale with zoom

Tags: cells, docked-cell, magnification

Is there any way to make your docked cell contents scale with the notebook magnification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
CreateWindow[DockedCells -> Cell["XXXX" , "DockedCell", 
  Magnification ->  
     Dynamic[AbsoluteCurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "Magnification"]]],
  WindowTitle -> "docked cell w magnification"]
```

[image]